# Want to download a file from AWS

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I have set up a cron job with a bash script to download a file from AWS s3 everyday. S3 contains many files with names like this: myfile_29_09_2014.tgz myfile_30_09_2014.tgz etc etc.

I want to be able to download this file each day based on the date.

My code at the moment looks like this, however this is not working. I believe there is some syntax error after `--include`, but I can't seem to figure out how to correct it.

```
yday=$(date --date yesterday "+%d_%m_%y")
rep="myfile_"
r="$rep$yday"

aws s3 cp s3://to/my/bucket/ ~/myDir/myFolder.tgz --recursive --exclude "*" --include `echo $r*`
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aws s3 cp s3://mydir/ ~/myfile/turtle.tgz --recursive --exclude "*.tgz" --include "*"`echo $(date --date yesterday '+%d_%m_%y')`"*"
```

has done the job.